# How to create SQLite query to insert a string that contains both " and '?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have to create an SQLite query to insert a string that contains both quotes and apostrophes. For example something like this

```
row = """Cristina O'Brien "Valenzuela" """
query = f"""INSERT INTO Actors (Actor)
            VALUES("{row}")"""

conn.execute(query)
```

But I have an error

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Valenzuela": syntax error
```

I understand that for SQL this string ends before `Valenzuela` but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is that apostrophes don't require any special handling, and you insert double quotes by doubling them.  But don't to that.  See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to let the library do the quoting.

```
row = """Cristina O'Brien "Valenzuela" """
query = "INSERT INTO Actors (Actor) VALUES (?);"

conn.execute(query, (row,))
```